# start self-compiled openvpn automatically in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, openvpn

Since I Upgrade from ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 18.04, openvpn stopped working
I uninstalled the openvpn 2.4.4 version and download the openvpn-2.3.18.tar.gz from the openvpn page
I extracted the file to /home/user/ folder and aplly the commands

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Now I can start the openvpn with the command

```
openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/client.conf
```

But I have to apply this command to a terminal window and keep it open, if I apply ctrl+c or colese the window, the openvpn service stops.

How to start the openvpn service at the boot and keep it alive?